# jQuery : button_click event not fires on first click and works on second click, why? How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, html

This is my code and the below submit button is not properly triggered during first click. During second click, the page get redirected to the next page using window.open() method. What could be the issue cause this?

```
<div>
    <button type="button" class="submit btn btn-default" id="btnSubmit">Submit 
    </button>
    <button type="button">Cancel</button>
</div>




<script>
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(e)
 {
  e.preventDefault();

  //btn Click validation and code submission goes here..

   alert("Form has been successfully submitted");
   window.open("http://....../viewmyrequest.aspx","_self"); 

  });

</script>
```

Comment: function not ended properly ? ");"

Comment: @Sabarish sorry it is missed only on stackoverflow. i have updated my question with correct syntax.

Comment: @user6549711 you need to include more information about what your click handler does. the code you posted works on the first click.

Answer (score 0):

Might be due to missing closing parenthesis.

```
<div>
    <button type="button" class="submit btn btn-default" id="btnSubmit">Submit 
    </button>
    <button type="button">Cancel</button>
</div>

<script>
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  //btn Click validation and code submission goes here..
   alert("Form has been successfully submitted");
   window.open("http://....../viewmyrequest.aspx","_self"); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry. I don't have any syntax error in my code. i missed it when i entered it in the stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please include your click event code in

$`(document).ready(function(){ });`

Like below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(e)
    {
    e.preventDefault();

    //btn Click validation and code submission goes here..
    alert("Form has been successfully submitted");
    window.open("http://....../viewmyrequest.aspx","_self"); 
  });
});
```

Please find the demo here https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/k9uym8cf/